# Implementar sistema recordarme

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

estoy haciendo una aplicación web y me gustaría saber cual es la mejor manera de implementar un sistema "Recordarme" o "Recordar mis datos".

Es decir quiero que al loguearse el usuario pueda marcar una casilla "Recordarme", y ya no tenga que volver a loguearse en el equipo.

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a [es.so].  Te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta agregando algo de información como que has probado o que has encontrado por Internet, y sería bueno que realices el [tour] y leer [ask]. La idea es ofrecer un [mcve] en todas las preguntas.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar cookies:

```
setcookie("EstaLogeado", true); //Esta línea la pones en el php cuando el login tenga exito

//Si quieres que la cookie tenga tiempo de expiracion de 1 hora
setcookie("EstaLogeado", true, time()*3600);

//Para comprobar si la cookie está definida
if($_COOKIE["EstaLogeado"] == true) {
    //Carga la pagina normal porque ya está logeado
}
```